# How to create a layout with two views placed vertically, filling the entry superview and with dynamic height?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I want to create a dynamic view with comments and the comment form using AutoLayout, change the height of textview dynamically depending on comment length. Like in Instagram:
[image]

There are a tableView and a textView.
I tried to add the following constraints
[image]

But it indicates error:[image]

When I specify static heights it works, but when I try to add >= <= it always shows an error.

Comment: Their is a third party class that you can try.I have used it and it works perfectly but it requires doing this functionality programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid inequalities. Either set the superview's bottom to be the bottom of the last view (you might have to raise all subviews' vertical compression resistance priority above that of the parent's... say 1000 while the parent is at 750). Or my suggested tactic, set the static height to an arbitrary value. Make a reference to the constraint to its appropriate view controller. Calculate the proper height programmatically in the view controller (just add up all the subview heights). Finally set the constraint's constant to the calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change height of view when keyboard appear try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd fromView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.bottomViewConstraint.constant = keyboardFrameEnd.size.height + 10.0;
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd fromView:nil];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.bottomViewConstraint.constant =  10.0;
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I want to change the height of textview dynamically depending on comment length.